# docker container freeze after exit command

Tags: docker, command, exit, freeze

I have multiple running containers. In some occasion i need to attach to a container with

```
docker exec -it container /bin/bash
```

being inside, as soon as i execute the command *exit* it freezes, no response.

I ssh another terminal and `docker ps` does respond. But I can do anything else. Besides restarting docker service.

Can someone explain me why does this happen? If I exit with

`control+p` `control+q`

everything works well.

note: docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Comment: what is the output of `journalctl` and `docker container logs`?

Comment: I am seeing this as well on certain docker hosts, control-p control-q works.